# Django nonrel error "No Module name models"

Tags: django, django-nonrel

Guys,
I Started playing with django-nonrel, and am trying to run my old django app on it. 
My app was done on django 1.2.1 & python 2.6.

When i fire up the local server, there are a couple of warnings but the server starts well.

But when i try to run the main page from the browser, django throws the following error

```
ImportError at /bytex
No module named bytexpro.bytex.models
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/bytex
Django Version: 1.3 beta 1
Exception Type: ImportError
Exception Value:    
No module named  bytexpro.bytex.models
Exception Location: E:\home\web\bytex\bytexpro\bytex\admin.py in <module>, line 1
Python Executable:  C:\python26\python.exe
...
```

My admin.py looks like this

```
from bytexpro.bytex.models import ItemGroup
from bytexpro.bytex.models import Item
from bytexpro.bytex.models import Supplier
....
```

Anything i i have forgotten to include?

Gath

Comment: have you tried `from bytex.models import ItemGroup` etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
from bytex.models import ....
```